# Grouping json using two duplicate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

```
{
    "ListBy": [{
        "Type": 12,
        "Basis": 808,
        "Code": "bad",
        "Rate": "10.00",
        "type1": 811,
    }, {
        "Type": 12,
        "Basis": 806,
        "Code": "bad",
        "Rate": "10.00",
        "type1": 810,
    }, {

        "Type": 13,
        "Basis": 805,
        "Code": "good",
        "Rate": "10.00",
        "type1": 810,

    }, {

        "Type": 13,
        "Basis": 805,
        "Code": "good",
        "Rate": "10.00",
        "type1": 810,

    }, {

        "Type": 13,
        "Code": "awesome",
        "Basis": 805,
        "Type": 810,
        "Rate": "10.00"

    }]
}
```

From `REST` service i am getting data as above. I have to group the above `json` by using `duplicates`(using type and code only) into the below grouped array.

Please help me by doing this using `underscore.js` or any pre-defined functions in javascript.

*Note: Type value will always be either `12` or `13`.*

```
{
    "ListBy": [{
            "Type": 12,
            "Code": "bad"
            "List": [{
                    "Basis": 808,
                    "type1": 811,
                    "Rate": "10.00"
                },
                {
                    "Basis": 806,
                    "type1": 810,
                    "Rate": "10.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": 13,
            "Code": "good",
            "List": [{
                "Basis": 805,
                "Type": 810,
                "Rate": "10.00"
            },
            {
                "Basis": 805,
                "Type": 810,
                "Rate": "10.00"
            }]
        },
        {
        "Type": 13,
        "Code": "awesome",
        "List": [{
            "Basis": 805,
                "Type": 810,
                "Rate": "10.00"
            }]

    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain ES6 you could do it with a `reduce` accumulator object, keyed by concatenation of the two key fields. The final result consists of the array of values of that accumulator object:

```js
const data = {ListBy: [{Type: 12,Basis: 808,Code: "bad",Rate: "10.00",type1: 811,}, {Type: 12,Basis: 806,Code: "bad",Rate: "10.00",type1: 810,}, {Type: 13,Basis: 805,Code: "good",Rate: "10.00",type1: 810,}, {Type: 13,Basis: 805,Code: "good",Rate: "10.00",type1: 810,}, {Type: 13,Basis: 805,Code: "awesome",Rate: "10.00",type1: 810}]};

const result = {
    ListBy: Object.values(
        data.ListBy.reduce( (acc, {Type, Code, Basis, Rate, type1}) => {
            (acc[Type+Code] = acc[Type+Code] || {Type, Code, List: []})
                .List.push({Basis, Rate, type1});
            return acc;
        }, {} )
    )
};

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The concatenation is a safe solution, given that the `Type` fields are always of the same length (i.e. 2 characters when 12 or 13 is converted to string). If this were not the case, a separator character should be used of which you are sure it does not occur in any of those key values.

Comment: how can i revert the data as the input given while sending it Through REST.

Comment: @hameed, that would be a different question. I would suggest you first try to find a way of doing that yourself. If you get stuck with a specific problem doing so, then please ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using lodash

```
 var groups = _.groupBy(data.ListBy, function(value){
        return value.Type + '#' + value.Code;
   });

    var result = _.map(groups, function(group){
        return {
            type: group[0].Type,
            code: group[0].Code,
            Lists: _.map(group,function(item){
                return {
                  Basis : item.Basis,
                  Type1 : item.type1,
                  Rate  :   item.Rate
                }
              })
        }
    });
```

If you want convert into original data

```
var result = [];

  _.each(data.ListBy,function(item){
      _.each(item.List,function(nestItem){
            result.push({
            Type : item.Type,
            Code : item.Code,
            Basis: nestItem.Basis,
            Type1: nestItem.Type,
            Rate:  nestItem.Rate
          });
       })
  });
```

Comment: working absolutely fine as expected. thanks for the help.

Comment: One more question here is [link]Dakota while sending data through rest call i have to split the data like the input that i had given above can you please look into this.

Comment: @hameed, it is OK to have further questions, but on StackOverflow you really should use the "Ask Question" button to ask new questions (which is no problem, and is the fastest way to getting an answer anyway). You can always back reference to this question in case it would be helpful information.

Comment: @hameed : i have just updated my comment , is that your expectation ?

Comment: Thankyou so much... that is what im expecting